# Best way to draw boxes around pure red areas of an image?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, draw, shapes

I have an image with various odd shapes (such as circles and squares) which are coloured pure red (rgb(255, 0, 0) exactly). I want to draw boxes around these shapes, but to do that I need the coordinates of each corner from each box. This is the part I am having difficulty with.

I basically want to go from this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

I have tried many different ways to achieve this, including parsing the y-axis until I find a shape and boxing it that way, starting from the very corners of the image and moving towards the middle (both methods of which don't work well for multiple shapes) and using external packages such as an OpenCV.

I could use OpenCV to achieve this, but given the constraints I was hoping there was a way to do it which doesn't require an external package.

Can anyone with a bit more machine vision experience point me in the right direction please?

Comment: In OpenCV it's like 10 lines of code... Why don't you want to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use the [Hoshen-Kopelman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoshen%E2%80%93Kopelman_algorithm) to determine the connected clusters of pixels with the given criteria (being red), then all you have to do is find their min/max regions (on x and y axes) to wrap them with a rectangle.

Comment: Thanks, an algorithm like this is exactly what I was looking for, will wait a couple hours before marking :)

Comment: Floodfill-Algorithm is an alternative. You can find implementations on the web (e.g. From [ccodeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6017/QuickFill-An-efficient-flood-fill-algorithm)). Or you try Freeman-Chain-code to get the contour and the object dimensions.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I will definitely have a look at both of those, you have been a great help.